# Jordan canonical forms and deficiency indices

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I'm solving a homework question that asks me to do the following:

***"List the five upper Jordan canonical forms for a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ with a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $4$ and give the corresponding deficiency indices in each case."***

I can't seem to understand what they mean by "$5$ upper Jordan canonical forms"? Isn't the answer unique and straightforward with the canonical form:

$$  J_=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 &\lambda & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

And what do they mean by deficiency indices? Are those the 
"$1$'s" that appear on top of each $\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other four Jordan canonical forms are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 0  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 0 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 1  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 0  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 0 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 1  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 1  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 0 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda   & 1  & 0  & 0 \\
0         & \lambda & 0  & 0 \\
0         & 0  & \lambda & 1 \\
0    & 0  & 0  & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The **deficiency indices** of a matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ are the numbers 
$$
n_{\pm}(A)=\dim\ker(A^*\mp i\cdot I_n)
$$
Since $\lambda$ is assumed to be real, computing these numbers should be straight forward.

Comment: Do you know why for a $2x2$ matrix there are only 2 deficiency indices, for a $3x3$ matrix there are only 3 deficiency indices, yet for a $4x4$ there are 5? Perhaps the formula above holds the answer?

Comment: There are always only two deficiency indices.

Comment: Why can't  $  J_=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 &\lambda & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
  \end{array} } \right]
$
be a Jordan canonical form?

Comment: It can be but it's the same as the third matrix I've listed up to reordering of Jordan blocks.

Comment: Oh ok, this makes sense, I can now see why $  J_=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 &\lambda & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
  \end{array} } \right]
$
wouldn't produce an extra form since it is also a reordering of Jordan blocks in the second matrix!

Comment: Exactly. The key is to keep track of all possible Jordan blocks.